# Safe way to update the API Key used for Youtube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We're planning to change the API Key that we're using for Youtube API v3 (dropping the old one in turn) and we're worried if there will be any penalties if the system somehow detects that same source is using a different API key. Can I clarify what is the safest way to do this? Can I just change the API Key without any worries? Thank you.

Comment: If you are updating your API key, there is no penalty with regards to using multiple API for a single source. BUT to have a smooth transition of changing API key, before removing the old one kindly test thoroughly  with the same setting to check if there will be any issue that will be encountered using the new API key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. Will test the API key after update as advised.